# Merge same columns in two different csv using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have several csv files

csv1:

```
date A B C
1991 1 2 3
```

csv2:

```
date A B C
1991 4 5 6
```

what I need is

csv3:

```
date A_csv1 A_csv2
1991    1      4
```

csv4:

```
date B_csv1 B_csv2
1991    2      5
```

csv5:

```
date C_csv1 C_csv2
1991    3      6
```

how to do it?

I am using python and pandas

but almost all search results is pandas.merge that is not the result I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` and `axis=1` parameters:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=['date'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, index_col=['date'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('csv1','csv2'))
print (df)
     csv1       csv2      
        A  B  C    A  B  C
date                      
1991    1  2  3    4  5  6
```

And then iterate by second level of `MultiIndex` with flatten columns and write to files:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(level=1, axis=1):
    g.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in g.columns]
    g.to_csv(f'{i}.csv')
    print (g)

      A_csv1  A_csv2
date                
1991       1       4
      B_csv1  B_csv2
date                
1991       2       5
      C_csv1  C_csv2
date                
1991       3       6
```

If files are in same folder:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files], axis=1, keys=files)
print (df)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! but I have at least 60 csv files how could I to make it in df1,df2,df3....df60?

Comment: I have 23 columns, how to do 2nd part?

Comment: @blueman010112 - Because python version, use  `g.columns= ['{}_{}'.format(b, a) for a, b in g.columns] `

Answer (score 0):

I always use pandas concatenation function:

```
df=pd.read_csv(“csv1.csv”)
do=pd.read_csv(“csv2.csv”)

DF = pd.concat([df , do ] , axis = 1)
```

You can try changing axis and other parameters to get it to concat correctly.